# Does SendGrid give "Marketing Email Statistics" API?

Tags: api, sendgrid

I'm using Sendgrid Marketing Email API. I couldn't find any endpoint for statistics after sending a Marketing Email. Do they have one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SendGrid's [General Statistics](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/index.html) and [Advanced Statistics](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/statistics_advanced.html) APIs to get data about Marketing Email Statistics. To separate out Marketing Email from any other kind of email, simply assign marketing emails a category while sending, you can look this up later from the API by using the `category` parameter.

For example, you might assign your email a category of `marketing` (you can add up to ten categories per email). Then you can make the following call to get marketing email statistics:

```
curl https://api.sendgrid.com/api/stats.get.json?api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&days=2&category=marketing
```